# Require CoreTelephony framework examples

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-telephony

Greetings everyone.

Can any one has a working example for the CoreTelephony framework? I dumped all the CoreTelephony headers using class-dump and added them to "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTelephony.framework". Now I'm following the Erica's tutorial (http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/08/iphone-notifications.html).

I added these following lines of code in my main.m,

```
  id ct = CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
  CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(
        ct, 
        NULL, 
        callback,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorHold);
```

but I'm getting a warning like,

**Implicit declaration of function "CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault()" and "CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver(...)".**

Can any one has full working example, which will explain how to get the CoreTelepony notifications?

Comment: Just an FYI... `CoreTelephony` is a private framework, so you're never going to get an app on the store if you try to use it directly.

Comment: @Dave: … unless you use 4.0 (although 4.0 SDK doesn't have CTTelephonyCenter either, it's still a private API.)

Comment: @Dave, I'm developing an app for my Jail-Break phone.

Comment: @Alexsander Akers, please ask a seperate question or google for it. Its easy to find.

Comment: @prathumca did you find any examples to use coretelephony framework how can i get all my phonecalls details in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been successfully using this private framework.  The warnings will **not** prevent your code from running, but you could put the following declaration in your code to get rid of the warning on `CTTelephoneCenterGetDefault()`:

```
id CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();
```

(you can do something similar for the `CTTelephonyCenterAddObserver()` warning, if you like)

Comment: I did it succesfully a while ago. Yes you're right, we need to put the "extern id CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault();" at the strting of your .mm file.

Answer (score 1):

I Did managed to get this framework to work partially - i still have some functions that i don't know their exact API - is there somewhere a full description of all the functions in this framework?

Answer (score 0):

The warning "Implicit declaration of function" means that the compiler cannot find a definition for the function in the header.

If the functions are defined in the header then you most likely did not import them correctly.

I would also note that you should not put any code in the main.m of an iPhone app. Most of the important code does not load until UIApplication is launched. Put the code in the application delegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` instead.

Comment: I know the why I'm getting the warning. But the problem is where can I find the definition for 'CTTelephonyCenterGetDefault()'?

I used the import statement #import<CoreTelephony/CoreTelephony.h> and the other required import statements properly. But not able to proceed further.

Do you have any Idea or any working code? If you have can you please share with me?

I'll try to move my code to "applicationDidFinishLaunching".

Comment: The comments to the Erica Sadun blogpost say that you cannot do this within Xcode but have to use something call the "Open SDK" (http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/03/iphone-open-sdk-vs-closed-sdk.html) One of the commenters report the same error you are getting. That blogpost is also two years old so I don't know how relevant it is today. You're working on something that is very, very non-standard. It might not have a simple answer or be possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

even using http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=281 - Open Tool Chain for 3.0 sdk (last tool chain i'd found)  - i couldn't have CoreTelephony working  - so it's seams to be impossible in last Xcode's/SDK's

Answer (score 0):

You can find the coretelephonyframework example [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreTelephonyDemo/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html)!

Comment: Can someone guide me how to use this example. Because when i keep this app active and have incoming call, the app is crashing. Any idea?